# В чем разница между «подарок» и « дар»?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Какой хочешь **подарок**?
>
> Какой хочешь **дар**?

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению одно отличается от другого?

> Купил в **подарок** девушке смартфон.
>
> Купил в **дар** девушке смартфон.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Дар — слово скорее из высокого регистра, без стилистических ограничений его употребляют либо только в устойчивых выражениях типа *Отдам щенка **в дар***, либо в значении 'талант, дарование', например: «У него есть дар пианиста».

Дарить девушке дар можно, пожалуй, только если вы ей поклоняетесь, как божеству, а во всех нормальных ситуациях делают *подарок*.

Comment: Смартфон в дар? Мелковато для дара :)